# Rails calculate percent true from a set of boolean values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am fairly new to using Ruby with the Rails framework and I have a question:

Using rails with postgresql, I have a customer model that has a boolean attribute named eft.  I am wondering how I would go about calculating the percent of customers that have an eft value of true.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to your customer model

```
def self.eft_percentage
  Customer.where(eft: true).count * 100 / Customer.count
end
```

and use

```
Customer.eft_percentage
```